# is there a limit on how many matplotlib plots shown in a single run?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am analyzing 2016 survey data taken by FreeCodeCamp[1](https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/2016-new-coder-survey). https://github.com/freeCodeCamp/2016-new-coder-survey

in particular, 2016-new-coder-survey/clean-data/2016-FCC-New-Coders-Survey-Data.csv

for some reason any additional plots I want to add are not displayed. giving the error

```
raise AttributeError('Unknown property %s' % k)
AttributeError: Unknown property type
```

my code is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_file = pd.read_csv('FCC_New_Coders_Survey_Data.csv', dtype={'AttendedBootcamp': float, 'CodeEventOther': object, 'JobRoleInterestOther': object})
AttendedBootcamp = data_file['AttendedBootcamp']
BootcampFullJobAfter = data_file['BootcampFullJobAfter']
BootcampRecommend = data_file['BootcampRecommend']
BootcampFinish = data_file['BootcampFinish']
Age = data_file['Age']
NetworkID = data_file['NetworkID']

AttendYes = data_file[data_file.AttendedBootcamp == 1]
AgeAttend = AttendYes['Age']
FinishYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampFinish == 1]
FinishNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampFinish == 0]
JobYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 1]
JobNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampFullJobAfter == 0]
RecYes = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 1]
RecNo = data_file[data_file.BootcampRecommend == 0]

var = [len(JobYes[JobYes.Age == i]) - len(JobNo[JobNo.Age == i]) for i in range(16, 60)]
x = range(16, 60)  
y = var

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.plot(x, y, 'go')
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Net Employment Difference (count)')
plt.title('Employement Discrepencies')
plt.xticks(x)
plt.xscale('linear')
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
plt.vlines(x, [0], y)           
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(15, 65, 5))
plt.xlabel('Age', horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center', x=1.05)
plt.show()

plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.title('bootcamp job')
plt.hist([JobYes['Age'], JobNo['Age']], histtype='bar', bins = 44, range=[16,60], label=['Job after camp', 'no job after camp'])
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.legend()


plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.title('Attend bootcamp')
plt.hist(AttendYes['Age'], histtype='bar', range=[16,60])
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.legend()


plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.title('bootcampfinish')
plt.hist([FinishYes['Age'], FinishNo['Age']], type='bar', range=[16,60], label=['finished', 'didn\'t finish'])
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.legend()





var1 = [len(RecYes[RecYes.Age == j]) - len(RecNo[RecNo.Age == j]) for j in range(16, 60)]
x1 = range(16, 60)  
y1 = var1
plt.figure(figsize=(8,8))
plt.plot(x1, y1)
plt.xlabel('Age')
plt.ylabel('Net reccomendation (count)')
plt.title('Age Sentiment')
plt.xticks(x1)
plt.xscale('linear')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If i were to comment out say, one of the first four plots, then the fifth plot would show.

Comment: There is no hard limit on the number of figures in matplotlib. There is a rcParameter `figure.max_open_warning`, which is set to 20 by default, so once you have more than 20 figures open, a warning will show up. However, still a lot more figures will be shown, as many as memory allows. The reason for the error is hence a different one, probably to do with one of the parameters of your 5th plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with the number of plots, but with a typo in the call to the fifth plot. As far as I know, there are no limits to the number of plots (besides your own computer's memory I guess)

In your fifth plot, you are calling `plt.hist(..., type='bar')` when it should be `plt.hist(..., histtype='bar')` as in the first four plots.

Comment: oh wow! I didn't even catch that (you meant to say fourth plot btw), works fine now. thanks! So why did it still show the fourth plot even though I had the wrong syntax?